# Android/data/package------my package name is missing

Tags: android, package

Android 4.4;
when my apk is installed.
there is no my package in Android/data/com.example.helloworld on mysdcard even the inner mem card

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld"  
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

there is some other package there,"com.android.browser" .etc
i try to delete the browser's folder,when i run the browser or restart the mobile the package appear again
but there is no package_name of mine,no where to find,but the app runs normal
on 4.4 we cant mkdirs there,only under the package name(but where is the name @.@)
so first:i dont wanna create this folder by my finger
second:no root,not all users know root

i want my package name back when install the apk.
thank you very much.

Comment: There is no Android/data folder under Android. There can be /mnt/sdcard/Android/data or /storage/0/Android/data or yet other paths on external or removable memory. If the package folder is not created automatically you can create it yourself. Use getExternalFilesDir().

Answer (score 0):

myb you should clear/delete some memory or something..its just my opinion btw im still new in stackoverflow and android development too.

Good Luck!